# SELECT FOR ALL ENTRIES vs LOOP SELECT SINGLE in ABAP

Tags: loops, select, abap, opensql

I am comparing the `SELECT FOR ALL ENTRIES` vs `LOOP SELECT SINGLE` and I am having a big difference between results.

Somebody can help me with this? What is the difference?

```
SELECT ekko~ebeln
    ekpo~ebelp
    ekko~bstyp
    ekko~bsart
    ekko~lifnr
    ekko~ekgrp
    ekko~aedat
    ekko~knumv
    ekko~zterm
    ekko~zbd1t
    ekpo~matnr
    ekpo~txz01
    ekpo~menge
    ekpo~meins
    ekpo~netpr
    ekpo~peinh
    ekpo~knttp
    ekpo~afnam
    ekpo~wepos
INTO TABLE t_ekpo
FROM ekko
INNER JOIN ekpo ON
    ekpo~ebeln EQ ekko~ebeln
WHERE ekko~lifnr IN s_lifnr
    AND ekko~ekgrp IN s_ekgrp
    AND ekko~ebeln IN s_ebeln
    AND ekko~aedat IN s_aedat
    AND ekko~bsart IN s_bsart
    AND ekko~bstyp EQ 'F'
    AND ekko~loekz EQ space
    AND ekpo~matnr IN s_matnr
    AND ekpo~ebelp IN s_ebelp
    AND ekpo~loekz EQ space.
```

`SELECT FOR ALL ENTRIES` **returns 9.528 records**

```
SELECT ebeln
    ebelp
    zekkn
    vgabe
    gjahr
    belnr
    buzei
    budat
    menge
    shkzg
FROM ekbe
INTO TABLE t_ekbe
FOR ALL ENTRIES IN t_ekpo
WHERE ebeln EQ t_ekpo-ebeln
    AND ebelp EQ t_ekpo-ebelp
    AND vgabe IN ('1','2').
```

`LOOP SELECT SINGLE` **returns 7.336 records**

```
LOOP AT t_ekpo INTO gs_ekpo.

    CLEAR gs_ekbe.

    SELECT SINGLE  ebeln
                 ebelp
                 zekkn
                 vgabe
                 gjahr
                 belnr
                 buzei
                 budat
                 menge
                 shkzg
    FROM ekbe
    INTO gs_ekbe
    WHERE ebeln EQ gs_ekpo-ebeln
        AND ebelp EQ gs_ekpo-ebelp
        AND vgabe IN ('1','2').

    APPEND gs_ekbe TO T_ekbe.

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: You mean difference in runtime, or in the actual results in the T_ekbe table?

Comment: is t_ekpo a sorted table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Table `EKBE` has more key fields than just `EBELN` and `EBELP`, so there can be more entries for a unique `EBELN`/`EBELP` pair. With the `SELECT SINGLE` you will not get these *extra* entries, with the `FOR ALL ENTRIES` you do. Depending on your needs only one of these will get you the correct data set.

Comment: He also needs to be careful, because if t_ekpo happens to be empty "FOR ALL ENTRIES" will not select no records as you might expect but all records (that fit the WHERE clause).

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add. 
`SELECT SINGLE` inside the `LOOP` is very bad idea.
If you need `ebeln`+`ebelp` from `ekpo` just select this two into additional table `lt_ekpo` (do not forget `DISTINCT` in this select) and use it for `FOR ALL ENTRIES`.